# How to share a single instance of an object without cluttering interfaces?

Tags: python

I'm writing a class that depends on a heavyweight object. Every instance of my class can share the same heavyweight object- I just want to avoid replicating it for efficiency's sake.

The easiest solution is to instantiate the heavyweight object and manually pass it in to each instance of my class, but I think this leads to bloated interfaces and ugly code, e.g.:

```
H = HeavyweightObject();
C1 = MyObject( H );
C2 = MyObject( H );
```

If I have a high-level class it might need three or four of these heavyweight items, so the interface gets progressively uglier.

I would really prefer it if I could automatically have every instance of the class I'm writing just automatically share the same instance of the heavyweight object. The first time MyObject is instantiated it could run some one-time code that creates an instance of HeavyweightObject, and then every subsequent instance of MyObject just uses that same instance of HeavyweightObject. My initial thought (as a C/C++ programmer) would be to do something like this when writing MyObject:

```
myobject.py:

H = None

class MyObject():
    def __init__( self ):
        if H == None:
            H = HeavyweightObject();
        self.H = H;
```

But I am getting an error here:

```
> if H == None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'H' referenced before assignment
```

I'm new to Python, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error and I don't even know if this approach actually does what I want it to.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a [singleton](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html)?

Comment: Looks like you want to make it a `global`?  Personally I'd go with passing it in explicitly, and find ways to DRY (e.g. bundle groups of related heavyweight objects into common structures/interfaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either uses H as global

```
def __init__( self ):
    global H
    if H == None:
        ...
```

or pass it as argument of the **init** method:

```
def __init__( self, H ):
    ...
```

you can also make H a variable from your class:

```
class MyObject():
    H = None
    def __init__( self ):
        if MyObject.H == None:
           ...
```

Comment: I think the global method does what I'm looking for. I'll leave a note to look into refactoring into a singleton object at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close. When using `__init__` on a class method, you need to pass it in as a parameter. Try this:

```
class MyObject():
    def __init__( self, H=None ):
        if H is None:
            H = HeavyweightObject();
        self.H = H;
```

Then you can call this like `obj = MyObject(H=H)`